# What is the difference between address of pointer and double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have this simple code of *node.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int x;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void unshift(Node **root, int value)
{
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->x = value;
    newNode->next = *root;

    *root = newNode;
}

//doesn't work if address of pointer is passed to unshift()
void foo(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        //pass address of pointer 
        unshift(&root, 4);
    }
}

//works with double pointer passed to unshift()
void bar(Node **root)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        //pass double pointer
        unshift(root, 4);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = NULL;

    //works
    // bar(&root);
    // printf("%p\n", root);

    //does not work
    foo(root);
    printf("%p\n", root);
}
```

Now there is a function `insert(Node **root, int value)`, which takes double pointer to root in order to change it (the newly created node will itself become a root). So obviously I can pass type `Node **` either way -> double pointer, or address of pointer. I do so in 2 separate function -> `foo(Node*)` and `bar(Node**)`. In foo I am thus passing address of the argument whereas in bar I simply pass its argument.

The issue is, only the `bar()` with double pointer will actually *change* the root pointer from main. The `foo()` function will not, even if passing the right datatype. That is, after call with `foo()`, the pointer root is `nil` (still null pointer as in declaration), whereas after `bar()` the pointer really `changed`. So why does compiler treats the addressof and pointer differently even though both are passing the same data? And why does not `foo()` also change the root pointer?

Comment: The address of a pointer is the location of the pointer.  A double pointer is a variable that contains the address of a double.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("%p\n", root);`  the output specifier `%p` requires a parameter of `void*` not `struct Node *`  so the statement should be: `printf("%p\n", (void*)root);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not "the same data". In `foo`, `&root` is the address of the formal argument `root` in `foo`, but in `bar` you are passing the address of the variable from `main`.  In other words, the value is changed in `foo` but that change is lost when `foo` returns because it did not update the value in `main`.